# Is there a mathematical model that models spectral power distribution curves?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, spectroscopy, data-analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

The experiment was aimed to find the specturm cruve of different light bulbs experimentally.

Is there a mathematical way to justify the results I obtained (the plotted graph)?
Would the equation in [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_power_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_power_distribution) under "physics of SPD cuves" in this wiki page be a valid equation to use?

Also, is it incorrect to call these spectral power distribution curves if the values I obtained is wavelength vs lux while a spectral power distribution is wavelength vs relative power?